# Async REST Queries and setting field values to global variables

Tags: javascript, rest

I'm having a problem wrapping my head around these sharepoint async REST queries. The problem is that an async REST query isn't setting a field.value because the assignment is happening to soon. Even when postponing the assignment in document.read() and ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(). I've pulled the REST command from [this microsoft technote](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539350(v=office.14).aspx#sectionSection5). There's a lot more going on in the script, but this is it in a nutshell:

```
var id = 1;
var global1 = '';
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() {
    getListDetails()
}, "sp.js");

function getListDetails(siteUrl) {

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('mylist');

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml(
    '<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\' /><Value Type=\'Integer\'>' + id.toString() + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>'
);
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceededgetListDetails),
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}


function onQuerySucceededgetListDetails(sender, args) {
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        global1 = oListItem.get_item('Title');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    myfield.value = global1;
});
```

I had considered not setting global1 as a global but within the `onQuerySucceededgetListDetails()` scope but I then run into other issues with the rest of the script.

What else can I do to force the assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using JQuery deferreds/Promises. Here is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //don't exectute any jsom until sp.js file has loaded.        
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', prepareTables);
    });    

function prepareTables() {
    getItemsWithCaml('External User Account Request').then(
            function (camlItems) {
                var listItemEnumerator = camlItems.getEnumerator();
                while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                    var listItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                    console.log(listItem.get_item('Title'));
                } console.log('Completed table prparation.');
            },
            function (sender, args) {
                console.log('An error occured while retrieving list items:' + args.get_message());
            }
        );   
}    

function getItemsWithCaml(listTitle) {
    //use of $.Deferred in the executeQueryAsync delegate allows the consumer of this method to write 'syncronous like' code
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();        
    var items = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(items);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this,
            function () { deferred.resolve(items); }),
        Function.createDelegate(this,
            function (sender, args) { deferred.reject(sender, args); }));

    return deferred.promise();
};
```

See this for more information:
http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2014/10/sharepoint-using-deferredspromises-or.html

Comment: I still haven't wrapped my head around JQuery deferreds/Promises, but it looks as though this is what I need. Thanks!